# Why doesn't this code convert the URL to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, html, shtml

This is in my 404.shtml file

```
<script> var oldUrl = window.location.href; var newUrl = oldUrl.toLowerCase; location.href = newUrl; </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `var newUrl = oldUrl.toLowerCase;` should be `var newUrl = oldUrl.toLowerCase();`, since it is a function.

Answer (score 3):

`toLowerCase` is a function so needs `()`:

```
<script> 
    var oldUrl = window.location.href; 
    var newUrl = oldUrl.toLowerCase(); 
    location.href = newUrl; 
</script>
```